# Osmdrord / osmbonuspack - customize navigation arrow (via MyLocationNewOverlay?)

Tags: android, osmdroid

How can I change the color of the current navigation/position arrow?

Now when there is no GPX info, a little man is shown. When movigng the current position / navigation arrow is green. I would like to be able to set another color.

Thanks: I am using osmdroid / osmbonuspack with gratitude for years!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far as I know you can not change the color of the arrow since it is just a default icon.
But you can use the built-in object of osmdroid maps to show your location with your own arrow/person icons.

```
MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationNewOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(mMap);
myLocationNewOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
myLocationNewOverlay.enableMyLocation();
```

replace the icons

```
myLocationNewOverlay.setDirectionArrow(yourPersonBitmap, yourArrowBitmap);
```

then just add this overlay to your map

```
mMap.getOverlayManager().add(myLocationNewOverlay);
```

Comment: Thank you, +1. Then I have to upgrade to a newer version.